# Curl get command not showing the data but showing only header information

Tags: elasticsearch

Am working on Elasticsearch server and using the curl command for posting, getting the data in Windows command line.

When I try to post the data using the curl -XPUT command the data appears getting inserted. But when I query the data back using curl-XGET I am not getting the data but only header information like Index number etc. Please see the queries and results below.

```
curl -XPUT "<server location>/megacorp/emp/1" -d "{""first_name"" : ""John"",""last_name"" :  ""Smith"",""age"" : "25"}"
{"_index":"megacorp","_type":"emp","_id":"1","_version":1,"created":true}
curl -XPUT "<server location>/megacorp/emp/2" -d "{""first_name"" : ""Jane"",""last_name"" :  ""Cooper"",""age"" : "35"}"
{"_index":"megacorp","_type":"emp","_id":"2","_version":1,"created":true}
curl -XPUT "<server location>/megacorp/emp/3" -d "{""first_name"" : ""Bradleey"",""last_name"" :  ""Cooper"",""age"" : "40"}"
{"_index":"megacorp","_type":"emp","_id":"3","_version":1,"created":true}

curl -XGET "<server location>/megacorp/emp/_search?q=last_name:Cooper"
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"megacorp","_type":"emp","_id":"2","_score":1.0},{"_index":"me
gacorp","_type":"emp","_id":"3","_score":1.0}]}}
```

Comment: can you post the mapping for emp type

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET '<server location>/megacorp`? my suspicion is that you're not storing the source and only indexing it.

Comment: Perhaps you've disabled dynamic mapping or your mapping is wrong? Ran the same queries and I got two hits with source in the response. What does `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/megacorp/emp/_mapping?pretty=1"` give you?

Comment: It appears I have disabled the source field in the mapping as per the output below. If so, how can I enable it? Thanks
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/megacorp/emp/_mapping?pretty=1"
{
  "megacorp" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "emp" : {
        "_source" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "properties" : {
          "age" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "first_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: After running this curl command I am getting my data displayed. Thanks to phuc77 and all.

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/megacorp" -d "{""megacorp"" : {""_source"" : {""enabled"" : true}}}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `curl -XGET "<server location>/megacorp/emp/_search?q=last_name:Cooper&_source=true"`

Comment: It is still not showing the data, only the header info as below.

{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"megacorp","_type":"emp","_id":"2","_score":1.0},{"_index":"me
gacorp","_type":"emp","_id":"3","_score":1.0}]}}

Thank You